# Send to server specific row from grid

Tags: extjs

i am have grid with columns (bookId, status,requestId,authorId,price) and i am want send to 
server only row where  column(status = 'sell')

```
     var request = {            
bookId: grid.getBookId(),          
info: []}       

store.each(function(rec, index, length) {            
request.info.push({
    requestId: rec.get('index'),
    authorId: rec.get('authorId'),
    price: rec.get('price')
});       });
```

how do I make a condition when sending to server

Comment: Wouldn't that just be another if clause before adding the data to the array?

Comment: about that?

var request = {            
bookId: grid.getBookId(),  
status='1',        
info: []}

Comment: See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to add specific records to your request, simply use an if clause before adding them to the array:

```
store.each(function(rec, index, length) {
    if (rec.get('status') == 'sell') {
        request.info.push({
            requestId: rec.get('index'),
            authorId: rec.get('authorId'),
            price: rec.get('price')
        });
    }
});
```